# Is this a reliable way to check the REQUEST_METHOD?

Tags: php

In my class, `AController`, I have the following method:

```
private function determineRequestMethod()
{
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $this->requestMethod = AController::POST;
  }
  else
  {
    $this->requestMethod = AController::GET;
  }
}
```

This method is called from the constructor. `POST` and `GET` are class constants, and `requestMethod` is a class variable.

PS - `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` does work on my server.

I have updated the method to specifically check for `GET` and to throw an exception when the request method is not `GET` or `POST`:

```
private function determineRequestMethod()
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == AController::POST) 
    {
        $this->requestMethod = AController::POST;
    } 
    else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == AController::GET)
    {
        $this->requestMethod = AController::GET;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Unexpected request method [' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . '].');
    }
}
```

Comment: There are [more methods than just GET and POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1).

Comment: You could also use `self::POST` and `self::GET` since this method lives within the same `AController` class, but I imagine you write the class name instead for clarity, which is also fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is realiable, you could actually do:

```
private function determineRequestMethod()
{
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $this->requestMethod = AController::POST;
  }
  elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
  {
    $this->requestMethod = AController::GET;
  }
}
```

If your class also supports other methods, you might want to put it in `else` condition otherwise your code is fine.

> PS - $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] does
>   work on my server.

It should work elsewhere too :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any other way to check the request method in PHP, so I would say it is. You may want to watch out for things like HEAD and other HTTP verbs though--treating them all as GET's may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks that is an excellent point. I have adjusted my method to reflect your advice.

Answer (score -1):

Why complicating life when there's an excellent native input filter in PHP: [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: -1 Because OP never said anything about input variables or filtering, which is a completely different domain from checking various HTTP request methods.

Comment: Dammit, is that hard to switch REQUEST_METHOD and return input filter based on the switch case? 

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
case 'GET': return filter_input_array(INPUT_GET);
case 'POST': return filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
default: return array();
}